# Apache2 414 error

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

Our hosted development server has a problem with Apache2; 414 Request URI too long.

I have had the host change LimitRequestLine 65536 in apache2.conf, and restart apache...still no change. This is a debian server.

The length of the URI causing the issue is 442 characters - and yes, it needs to be, as it is a return from a bank to wordpress/woocommerce, and the only way to make this particular bank API work. (POST not an option)

Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, hosted you say?  If you have name based virtual hosts, the server-wide limit is set by the first-listed host. So perhaps the LimitRequestLine being updated is having no effect, b/c your host isn't the first listed.

Comment: @bishop how to determine "name based virtual hosts"? Is that when they have the domains listed in /apache2/sites-available? Well they aren't - but I haven't delved into exactly how they have it configured.

Comment: It's when they have one IP serving many web sites with different domains and content.  Eg, fastfood.com and nurseryrhymes.com both served by same Apache service on IP 1.2.3.4.  [You can use a reverse IP lookup to determine if you're sharing an IP.](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/web-sites-on-web-server/)

Comment: Ok, so it is a name based virtual host. 91 other domains on that server.

Comment: Sometimes, serves have a WAF in front and that piece of hardware is capable of enforce rules such as a maximun number of params/length in URL requests.

Comment: So is the first listed site the "default" in sites-available? If so, how do I make the change within that vhost file?

Comment: @alfabravo : WPF? Is that a firewall description?

Comment: According to [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-configure-the-apache-web-server-on-an-ubuntu-or-debian-vps), the listing order is configured in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` down at the bottom where there are a bunch of `Include`.  Whichever is included first is the default, and that virtual host would need to have limit set.

Comment: @Onyx My bad. It's WAF and stand for Web Application Firewall. I bring it as a possibility cause I had a problem with number of params in GET and was due to a rule enforced there, long before it hitted my Apache.

Comment: Again I ask, what is preventing the use of POST or SESSION?

Comment: @Deryck : I have no control over what is returned by the bank :(

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. It turned out it was a Wordpress "feature" that I knew nothing about in 
Security-> Tweaks -> Prevent Long URL Strings

Wasted a day on that. Thanks Wordpress.